# mongoose findById works when I use a string literal but not when I reference a property of an Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a really strange problem in Mongoose.

This line correctly finds the `Round`:

```
models.Round.findById("555ec731385b4d604356d8e5", function(err, roundref){
            console.log(roundref);
            ....
```

This line DOES NOT

```
models.Round.findById(result.round, function(err, roundref){
            console.log(roundref);
```

I've console logged `result` and it clearly is an object containing the property round:

```
{round: "555ec731385b4d604356d8e5", selection: 1, time: 20}
```

Why won't `findById` work without a literal?

Comment: Are you sure `result` is a javascript Object and not a JSON String?

Comment: @victorkohl you were right! It was a string!! Please make as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `result` is a JSON string, calling `.round` would return `undefined`.

Try converting the JSON to a javascript object first:

```
result = JSON.parse(result);
models.Round.findById(result.round, function(err, roundref){
        console.log(roundref);
```